# why are $e^{2x}$ and $e^{x^2}$ inequal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VanbX.png)

From the index rules I learned from school, $a^{x^2}=a^{2x}$
Does it work the same for the natural constant?
Why is it?

Comment: Because $2x\neq x^2$...Pay close attention to the parentheses in your powers.

Comment: The real question is, why $(a^b)^c \neq a^{(b^c)}$ ...

Comment: You're likely confusing $e^{x^2}$ with $(e^x)^2$.

Comment: Put $x=1$ and ask yourself whether $e^2=e$. Simple examples often illuminate problems which seem complicated. I guess that those who have explored the conventions for exponents in comments and answers will have helped you to see how this kind of confusion might arise. Very important to clarify these things as you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between ${(a^b)}^c$ and $a^{(b^c)}$.

The first simplifies to ${(a^b)}^c=a^{bc}$ but the second does not.

If no brackets are used, it is assumed that it means $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$, the one that does not simplify.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to assume that exponentiation is associative; and in fact, it is not. (Counter example: $2^{2^3} = 2^8$ but $ (2^2)^3 = 2^6$) Thus in general,
$a^{(x^2)}$ (which is what we usually mean when we write $a^{x^2}$ ) is not necessarily equal to $(a^x)^2 = a^{2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$ a^{x^2}=a^{2x }$ is not true for all $x$ !

We have

$$a^{x^2}=a^{2x } \iff a^{x^2-2x}=1 \iff x^2-2x=0 ,$$

Hence $a^{x^2}=a^{2x } \iff$ $x=0$ or $x=2.$

Comment: Why the downvote ???

Comment: Probably some user has made a mistake. +1 for me.